# Pegar valores de select e somar respectivos dados

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
       <label for="servico">Serviço</label>
       <select>
    <option value="200">Escapamento / Montagem R$ 100</option>                             </select>

      </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valorTotal">Total</label>                                 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorTotal" name="valorTotal" value="" readonly >
  </div>
 </div>
```

Bom dia gente.

Tenho um select que apresenta o nome do serviço, valor da peça e montagem. Eu queria que ao selecionar o serviço, fossem somados 200 + 100 e apresentados em outro input.

Esse seria meu select:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
       <label for="servico">Serviço</label>
    <select>
<option value="200">Escapamento / Montagem = 100</option>                             </select>

  </div>          </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <label for="valorTotal">Total</label>                                 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorTotal" name="valorTotal" value="" readonly >
  </div>
 </div>
```

É possível eu fazer isso com JQuery?

Comment: sempre vão vir separados por `/` e esse `select` está meio estranho ele é `<select></select>`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz a correção, estava faltando a tag select e acrescentei pra executar o html. Veja se dá pra entender agora.

Comment: agora você mudou a questão? é assim mesmo que é para vir? uma está com igual a outra um `R$`, por favor coloque corretamente como é a verdadeira forma?

Comment: Oi @virgilio mudei bem na hora que vc me respondeu. Desculpe. Mas esta última modificação é o meu problema. Obrigada

Comment: eu coloquei um exemplo com **=** ve se está correto pra você? tem um padrão olha como seria!

Comment: Ficou do jeito que preciso. Muito obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se existir esse padrão pode ser feito assim:

```js
$('#select1').on('change', function(e) {
  var n1 = parseInt($(this).val());  
  var n2 = parseInt($(this).text().split("=")[1].trim());
  $('#result').val(n1 + n2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<select id="select1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="100">Escapamento / Montagem = 100</option>
  <option value="200">Escapamento / Montagem = 200</option>
  <option value="300">Escapamento / Montagem = 300</option>
<select>

<input type="text" readonly id="result" />
```